# How to call back a function in Angular 4 Component from Service

Tags: angular

I have a component that calls a service. The service makes a http call. On receiving a response I want to call a function in the component from the service. How can it be done?

This is my component

```
import { ExportService } from '../menu/export.service';
export class Component {

   constructor(public exportService: ExportService) {
   }

   functionToCallFromService(){
   }

   export(){
       this.exportService.export()
   }
}
```

Here is my Service, which makes an HTTP Post call. downloadFile() is just a function in the service that gets called once the response is received. Is there any way I can call the functionToCallFromService() of the component, once the response is received

Service is as follows

```
@Injectable()
export class ExportService {
 export() {
    this._http.post(urlToMakePostCall, formData, { responseType: 'blob' 
    }).retry(3)
     .subscribe(response => { this.downloadFile(response, 
     filename)},
     error => { throw new Error(error); });

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call component method from service? (angular2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788458/how-to-call-component-method-from-service-angular2)

Comment: Return an observable from the service? Have an explicit callback argument to `export`?

Comment: @Pipo Tells, the usual way is that the services only serve Observables, it's in the component where you subscribe to the observable and then you call the function

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call a component method from your service. Thats not a really good idea in general, as your service will end up being usable only by a single controller. What you should do, is returning a value from the service and handle that value from your controller (there is no need to return an Observable or a Promise, it can be literally anything)

```
import { ExportService } from '../menu/export.service';
export class Component {

   constructor(public exportService: ExportService) {
   }

   functionToCallFromService(){
   }

   export(){
       this.exportService.export().subscribe(value => console.log(value))
   }
}

@Injectable()
export class ExportService {
 export() {
    const responseType = 'blob';
    return this._http.post(urlToMakePostCall, formData, { responseType })
        .retry(3)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @nicowernli, I changed the design as mentioned by you.