# Angular 8, can checkbox value pass onto components? not not in a parent/child relation

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular6, angular7, angular8

```
<input type=checkbox [(ngModel)]="myCheckBox" (ngChanged)="!myCheckBox">
```

for example, if I want the code above to pass the "checked" value, which is "true or false" to other components, so its contents can react based on "myCheckBox" true | false, and they are not in a parent child relationship, is there any way I can do that? Please help, really apprecipate it!!!!

Comment: if the two components are at time in the app, check too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59699155/execute-function-between-components/59699411#59699411

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this using `rxjs` with `BehaviourSubject`

You have to put some value in checkbox and then `onchange` you have to call a function which notifies the subscriber in your another component. I am writing up a very basic example for you.

In your `sender.component.html` you can do like this

```
<input type=checkbox [(ngModel)]="myCheckBox" (ngChanged)="!myCheckBox" (change)="notifyOtherComponent()">
```

Then in your `service.ts` you can do like this

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
public currentMessageSubscriber = this.messageSource.asObservable();


notify(message: any) {
   this.messageSource.next(message)
}
```

And in your `sender.component.ts` you can do like this

```
  constructor(private __dataService : DataService){}

  notifyOtherComponent(){
   this.__dataService.notify({msg : 'do something'}) 
  }
```

And in your listener.component.ts you can subscribe to `BehaviourSubject` type `Observable` to listen the latest value like this

```
constructor(private __dataService : DataService){}

ngOnInit() {
   this.__dataService.currentMessageSubscriber.subscribe((data : any)=>{
    console.log(data) // output : {msg : 'do something'}
  }) 
}
```

In this way you will be sending data to observable from one component and listening that data into another component.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it by different methods. For example: with EventEmitter or rxjs( Subject, BehaviourSubject);

In my example, I did through BehaviourSubject.
[stackblitz-link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7mfsdr)