# Shared-Service isn't working (reciever subscription doesn't get data)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, progressive-web-apps

Hello so my problem is that I am trying to make a shared-service because I need an array in an other component. It seems like the "sender" class is working also as the service class itself. Just the "reciever" class isn't getting any data through the description. What do I need to change here to get it working?

Service:

```
 import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Note } from '../note/note-data';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    exchangeData$: Observable<Note[]>
    private dataSubject = new Subject<Note[]>()

    constructor() {
        this.exchangeData$ = this.dataSubject.asObservable()
    }

    exchangeData(data) {
        console.log(data)
        this.dataSubject.next(data)
    }
}
```

Sender Class:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NoteComponent } from 'src/app/note/note-component';
import { Note } from 'src/app/note/note-data';
import { Content } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/r3_ast';
import { ContentSearcher } from './searcher/ContentSearcher';
import { DataService } from './ChangeDataService/DataService';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'noteApp';

  public notes: Note[] = [
    new Note("example title 1", "blablablalblalalblablabla", new Date(5000), new Date(5000)),
    new Note("example title 2", "example description 2", new Date(5000), new Date(5000)),
    new Note("example title 3", "example description 3 noch mehr blablalblalbla", new Date(5000), new Date(5000))
  ]

  public constructor(private dataService:DataService) {
    this.dataService.exchangeData(this.notes)
  }

  deleteNote(note: Note) {
    var index = this.notes.indexOf(note, 0);
    this.notes.splice(index, 1); 
  }
```

Reciever class:

```
    import { Component, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { ContentSearcher } from './ContentSearcher';
import { Note } from '../note/note-data';
import { DataService } from '../ChangeDataService/DataService';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'content-searcher',
    templateUrl: './content.searcher.html',
    styleUrls: ['./content.searcher.css']
})

export class ContentSearcherComponent implements OnDestroy {
    public notes: Note[] = []
    private subscription:Subscription

public constructor(private dataService: DataService) {

    console.log("notes (constructor before init): "+this.notes)
    this.subscription = this.dataService.exchangeData$.subscribe((data) =>   {
        this.notes = data
        console.log("notes in content.searcher (CONSTRUCTOR): "+this.notes)
    })
    console.log("subscription: "+this.subscription)
}

searcher: ContentSearcher = new ContentSearcher()
matchingNotes: Note[]


onKey(event) {
    console.log("notes in content.searcher: "+this.notes)
    const inputValue = event.target.value
    if (this.notes != null) {
        this.matchingNotes = this.searcher.searchContent(inputValue, this.notes)
    }
}

getMatchingNotes(): Note[] {
    return this.matchingNotes
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
}

}
```

Comment: I answered this kind of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59744286/angular-8-can-checkbox-value-pass-onto-components-not-not-in-a-parent-child-re/59745296#59745296) I hope this will help you

Comment: try use ngInit to subscribe or sendData, not the constructor

Comment: ngInit is also not working :/

Comment: @Schmidi not `ngInit` its `ngOnInit`. Please see my given link you will get the idea

Comment: @FahadHassan I meant ngOnInit sry, tried to orientate myself on your answer but still can't get it running

Comment: Try to convert your `Subject` to `BehaviourSubject`

Comment: @FahadHassan also tried that but it didn't changed anything :/

Comment: @Schmidi can you create stackblitz for your problem?

Comment: @FahadHassan so basicly displaying the whole project there? Or only a specific part?

Comment: just the code that shows your problem

Comment: Well that's basicly the code above? I mean sender of the data, shared-service and the data-reciever which doesn't work